# How to deny the point just at the beginning of the textfield Flutter

Tags: flutter, textfield, inputformatter

I have a problem with my textfield, I set it allowing only numbers and banning the comma, minus and space that I didn't need.
But now I have a problem with the point because I don't want to ban it completely but remove the possibility of putting it as the first digit, leaving the availability to use it after a number. And then if it were possible I would also like to put the limit of being able to write it once.
Here is my code:

`inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(RegExp('[-, ]'))],`

Searching online I found an answer in which he explained that to allow less only at the beginning it was enough to use this:

`inputFormatter: FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(new RegExp("^-?\\d*")),`

I tried replacing `-` with `.` and `allow` with `deny` but it didn't work.

(This is what I got: `inputFormatter: FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(new RegExp("^.?\\d*"))`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regexp to allow you use digits with point inside

```
^\d+(\.\d+)?$
```

[Sandbox with regex](https://regex101.com/r/xiL2Xd/1)